# uitableview chrashes the app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

hy there

i have a big problem. recently i am making an promotional app. The core of my app is an navigation controller. When i press the tab bar it opens a new view in that view there is a button that opens a tableview. So far so good. Everything works well. Except if i change the table view to grouped and static cell( i really need that) the program will still work except if i go into the table view and press the tab bar for another view and then press the tab bar for this view  it'll crash the app. However if i go back from the table view it'll work fine.
I didn't program a thing concerned whit the table.

This is my code for button:

```
Class *detailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"map"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

then open uitableview which is grouped. Class which is UITableViewController is empty because it has static cells.

This is error when app crash:

> 0x14f209b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi

When I chose tableview style Plain it works. When I chose tableview style Grouped it crash app.

Thank you

Comment: Anyway the problem is obviously in your code, so, it's impossible to say anything until we can look what you did in it.

Comment: Yes, If I can see the code then I will answer specifically for the solution.

Comment: it would be helpful if you add some lines of code,that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the UITableViewDelegate even if you don't have any code

http://vimeo.com/1014998

This tutorial video should be helpful.